# Need your assistance to understand a point for Update status in Android

Tags: java, android, updates

I'm trying to understand some points in Android applications,

Actually i'm working on some university project app, And i've to publish regular base notifications on that app and but problem is How to do that?

I mean is that possible i just put notifications and users open that app and they get the latest news, But kindly please help What do i need to do in that case please help.

Help would be appreciated!

Comment: Better to search on **Google**...We cant help you without any code.....

Answer (score -2, accepted):

ok, do one thing for notification use GCM(Google cloud messenger) and to update the latest news and all you need to interact with the webservices part.search in google there are so many examples on GCM notification and Json webservices in android

If you need help in programming part.I can assist you

Comment: welcome,if you like this.please accept the answer and vote to support

Comment: Of course but it's showing "wait 5 minutes to accept the answer".. i'd accept your answer after 5 minutes surely :)

Comment: ok thanks don't forget

Comment: Surely but sorry i can't vote up, Don't have sufficient reputations ..